# My dataframe appears to have column names, but when I attempt a lm() function and name columns r says 'object not found'

Tags: r

I'm still very new to R, I have no other coding experience, and I don't understand some of the fundamentals, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to do a multiple regression on the data set found at:
https://studysites.sagepub.com/dsur/study/DSUR%20Data%20Files/Chapter%207/ChildAggression.dat

The website's answers don't mention any transformation of the data, but suggest one could just go ahead with the lm() function.

```
aggro <- read.delim("ChildAggression.dat", header = TRUE)
aggro.reg1 <- lm(Aggression ~ Parenting_Style + Sibling_Aggression, data = aggro)
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Aggression' not found

I don't understand why it isn't finding the object.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does `names(aggro)` return?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default separator for `read.delim` is `\t`, but the file isn't tab separated. You want `sep = ""` instead.

Having read in the file as you did:

```
aggro <- read.delim("ChildAggression.dat", header = TRUE)
```

there are numerous ways to detect that something is wrong:

```
> dim(aggro) #number of columns is clearly wrong
[1] 666   1
> names(aggro) #only one long concatenated column name
[1] "Aggression.Television.Computer_Games.Sibling_Aggression.Diet.Parenting_Style"
> colnames(aggro) #only one long concatenated column name
[1] "Aggression.Television.Computer_Games.Sibling_Aggression.Diet.Parenting_Style"
```